# Toggling one element's display that has a certain class when clicking on the button "corresponding" to it using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```html
{% for i in range(l) %}
  <button class="t_b_show" onclick="func_show(this);"> Show this list</button>
  <div class="toggle_div" hidden="true">  
    <ul>
      <li> {{list1[i]["name"]}}</li>
      <li> {{list1[i]["note"]}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="t_b_hide" hidden="true" onclick="func_hide(this);">Hide this list</button>
{% endfor %}
```

javascript:

```
function func_show(theButton) {
  subNoteDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle_div');
  showButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('t_b_show');
  hideButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('t_b_hide');
  thisElement = theButton;
  console.log(thisElement);//shows the clicked element in the console, meaning the element itself                                         passes to the function
  
  if(showButtons.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < showButtons.length; i++){
      if(showButtons[i] == thisElement){
        let j = i;
        i = showButtons.length;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(j);
  subNoteDivs[j].setAttribute('hidden', false);
  hideButtons[j].setAttribute('hidden', false);
  showButtons[j].setAttribute('hidden', true);
}


function toggle_func_hide(theButton) {
  subNoteDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle_div');
  showButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('t_b_show');
  hideButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('t_b_hide');
  thisElement = theButton;
  console.log(thisElement);//shows the clicked element in the console, meaning the element itself                                         passes to the fuction
  if (hideButtons.length > 0){
    for (let i = 0; i < hideButtons.length; i++){
      if(hideButtons[i] == thisElement){
        let j = i;
        i = hideButtons.length;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(j);
  subNoteDivs[j].setAttribute('hidden', true);
  hideButtons[j].setAttribute('hidden', true);
  showButtons[j].setAttribute('hidden', false);
}
```

**Short explanation about the code for context:**

I am trying to rite an app that allows the user to write notes on subjects, the subjects are added by the user and tables on them are created to which they can add notes on the subjects.

The program works fine but displaying all the tables makes the page look hideous, and so I want to give the user the option to show the tables they want by clicking on a button "corresponding" to each table,
and hide them by clicking on a button as well.
I can't use ids because the number of elements is dynamic and therefore I can only set classes which copies of the same elements created with the tables have.
And so I tried writing both functions above: By clicking on a button next to a table, a function is called, which after finding out the index of the button clicked within the HTMLCollection of same class elements, changes the attributes of the elements in the functions above that are in the same index as the button clicked in their respective HTMLCollection of the elements with the same class.

**The problems I faced:**

One problem is, I don't know how to make javascript check which index the clicked button is, I tried the above code but it always gives the error that j is undefined meaning the comparison in the if statement is not the correct way of checking which index the clicked button is in.
I searched for a another way to check but didn't find how the correct comparison is done.
I also tried using the "array.indexof(theElement)" method but it gives an error "indexOf is not a function".

A second one i encountered before, unrelated to the above problem is "setAttribute is not a function", too.

I tried searching for a fix all day but couldn't solve it, please help. And if there is another way to acheive the goal, that would also work.

In the code above I used a list instead of a table for simplicity's sake, as the code above is only similar to the code I am working on

Also I am very new to programming and this is my first question so sorry if the problem turns out to be silly or the the problem is poorly clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typical case for event delegation (There is plenty answers about).

you may also have look on :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling

also prefer to use css `display: none;`
or
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({target: btn}) =>
  {
  if (!btn.matches('button.t_b_show, button.t_b_hide')) return;
  
  let method = btn.matches('button.t_b_show')
             ? 'nextElementSibling'
             : 'previousElementSibling'
             ;
  
  btn.classList.toggle('setHidden');
  btn[method].classList.toggle('setHidden');
  btn[method][method].classList.toggle('setHidden');
  })
```

```css
.setHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="t_b_show" > Show this list</button>
<div class="toggle_div setHidden" >  
  <ul>
    <li> list 0a </li>
    <li> list 0b </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="t_b_hide setHidden" > Hide this list </button>
<hr><button class="t_b_show" > Show this list</button>
<div class="toggle_div setHidden" >  
  <ul>
    <li> list 1a </li>
    <li> list 1b </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="t_b_hide setHidden" > Hide this list </button>
<hr>
<button class="t_b_show" > Show this list</button>
<div class="toggle_div setHidden" >  
  <ul>
    <li> list 2a </li>
    <li> list 2b </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="t_b_hide setHidden" > Hide this list </button>
<hr>
<button class="t_b_show" > Show this list</button>
<div class="toggle_div setHidden" >  
  <ul>
    <li> list 3a </li>
    <li> list 3b </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="t_b_hide setHidden" > Hide this list </button>
<hr>
```